# How to change a discord nickname to whatever the user writes using a bot discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
if message.content.startswith(f'Imagine having a name as dumb as {#name}'):
Nick = (#message author)
#change nickname of Nick to {#name}
await message.channel.send('Ikr')
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple regex

```py
import re

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    content = message.content.lower() # The actual content of the message in lowercase
    pattern = "imagine having a name as dumb as (.{0,32})" # Max length for nicks is 32 characters 
   
    if (nick := re.findall(pattern, content)): # Walrus operator, need python 3.8+
        await message.author.edit(nick=nick[0]) # Editing the actual nick
```

Comment: File "main.py", line 75
    if (nick := re.findall(pattern, content):
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I forgot a closing parenthesis

Comment: oh, there's no error anymore but it still doesn't work

Comment: It works like a charm to me, you must be doing something wrong

Comment: hmmm maybe? I did exactly what's there tho?

Comment: Did you add the `client.event` / `bot.event` decorator? Sorry for late response